# Like Box repeating posts since January 2012

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-likebox

Did anyone notice that Like Box is repeating all the posts from a page at least one time (and the repetition is increasing for every new post), but also making a mess going down in the older posts?

how to solve it? I'm using the code generated by FB on my webpage and also testing several pages in the official FB tools test page I always get the same error.

thanks in advance for the suggestions.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see it.  I went to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/ and tried 4 different pages in the url and none of them had repetition, nor did it make any mess.  Can you tell us what pages you're seeing this happen on?

Comment: Today, after a couple of weeks of observed repetition of all the series of posts after January, it seems working fine at least for the old posts. I've posted a new link and now I see it appearing 2 times in Like Box and just 1 in the page http://www.facebook.com/pages/Iridra-Srl/102825893127078

Comment: that's the webpage where I'm using the Like Box http://www.iridra.eu

Comment: when I made my tests I just looked for pages with posts dated after January 2012, and for all of them (2-3 pages I don't remember precisely, it was weeks ago) I got the same kind of wrong behaviour; all the pages were looking perfect if accessed directly, but wrongly repeated in the Like Box

Comment: even today, if you go down in the streaming, after clicking 2 times "show more" you get the series starting again from the more recent post and you can't reach the real start line of the page (that's what I was defining as mess) ... I also tested 2 browsers (chrome and firefox) and different pc's .. still same results

Comment: also this page is producing the same error, at least here: http://www.facebook.com/pages/WATACLIC/126968830676062

Answer (score 0):

I see the dupes.  Definitely a bug.  File a report at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs and post the bug # here so other people who stumble upon this question knows the answer is it is a bug.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks ... it seems I'm not allowed to file reports in the bugs section, so I hope you can do it.

Comment: Sure you are, unless somehow you got yourself banned.  Anyone is.  I'm nobody special. I'm here on StackOverflow on my own time. I don't work for Facebook nor for StackExchange.  I am **not** going to file bug reports for you. Sorry. But your answer is clearly that this is a bug

Comment: oppss sorry, I thought you were working for FB; btw it says "You must be a registered developer to create bugs" and I'm not a developer and consequently also not registered :-). I was just trying to find a proper way to let the FB team about the bug but yet I haven't found an easy way (and my time for this is limited indeed) ... anyway thanks for your comments